# Using 3rd party libraries in WinRT component

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to use some image processing in my windows app (C#)

My plan is to create a WinRT component project in C++ do all the image processing there and reference the WinRT project in my app.

My question is if i use a 3rd party library like OpenCV in my WinRT project (as additional library dependancy) will it get automatically included in my app or do i have to do something else?

Can anyone please give the procedure to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the source code repository, I get the impression that [EmguCV](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV/) already provides what you are trying to accomplish. There is a specific *Windows 8.1* *EmguCV* project in the repository, although I do not know the status of the project.

Comment: Yes, i have seen emgucv it's good enough but i want to know the procedure in general if i require it for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.

The way to do it is just normally add the include directories and library dependencies for the WinRT component project in C++, then if you are not using static libraries you have to include the 3rd party dlls in the app which consumes WinRT component.